# Making a relatively complex datetime function more pythonic

Tags: python

I'm working on a function that returns a specific set of times for a given timezone and a given frequency; day, week, month.  For any given timezone and a frequncy the function will return the unixtime hour start and unixtime hour end of the last full frequency given.  For example, the last full day, the last full 7 days or the last full month.

```
import calendar
import pytz
import time

from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

def get_international_dates(timezone, frequency):
    tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
    today = datetime.now(tz).date()
    midnight = tz.localize(datetime.combine(today, time(0, 0)), is_dst=True)
    last_full_day_midnight = int(midnight.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime("%s"))
    if frequency == 'd':
        day_end = last_full_day_midnight - 3600
        day_start = last_full_day_midnight - (3600 * 24)
        prev_day_end = day_end - (3600 * 24)
        prev_day_start = day_start - (3600 * 24)
        return {'start': day_start, 'end': day_end, 'prev_start': prev_day_start, 'prev_end': prev_day_end}
    if frequency == 'w':
        week_end = last_full_day_midnight - 3600
        week_start = last_full_day_midnight - (3600 * 24 * 7)
        prev_week_end = week_end - (3600 * 24 * 7)
        prev_week_start = week_start - (3600 * 24 * 7)
        return {'start': week_start, 'end': week_end, 'prev_start': prev_week_start, 'prev_end': prev_week_end}
    if frequency == 'm':
        month_length = calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month - 1)
        month_end = last_full_day_midnight - 3600
        month_start = last_full_day_midnight - (3600 * 24 * month_length[1])
        prev_month_end = month_end - (3600 * 24 * month_length[1])
        prev_month_start = month_start - (3600 * 24 * month_length[1])
        return {'start': month_start, 'end': month_end, 'prev_start': prev_month_start, 'prev_end': prev_month_end}
```

This function works as it should, but it seems pretty messy and un-pythonic.  What should I do to make this more clean, concise and pythonic?

Comment: Perhaps that'd suit more for [codereview.se]

Comment: You could gain a lot of clarity by just factoring out each conversion variant. E.g. `if frequency == 'd': get_international_daily_dates(...)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making this more pythonic is probably not that easy as it's just statements. But you can certainly improve your code by:

1. Not using magic numbers. This will make sure you code is configurable and scalable. Sure, the parameters wont change as they haven't over the last thousands of years, but you never know. Storing constants is always a good habit.
2. Using elif instead of multiple ifs, with only one possible outcome. You are returning anyway, but again, it's a good habit to just get used to it.

If you really want "lighter" code, since this is almost only configuration that'll never change, you could choose an approach where you outsource the configuration into a persistent file (for example xml).

Another thing you could do is turning this into a [builder/factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that allows you to create even more dynamic types. It'll be more encapsulated, but at the end of the day, the logic will almost stay the same.

Comment: could you explain `builder/factory`?

Comment: These patterns are mostly used for Java/C# etc and not that common in python, as python is more dynamic itself already - but you can still use them. The idea is to create a class that can assemble an object or a datastructure by calling methods on an instance of that builder class. It's kind of like having optional parameters, but more type-safe. It's just a suggestion and probably not worth the effort to implement in this scenario. Like I already mentioned, it'd cut your code into smaller pieces. I'll also link the wikipedia page that explains the pattern in my original answer.